# Mercado Pago, item no contiene una definicion para Currency_id

Tags: c#, mercadopago

Estoy intentando implementar Mercado Pago en mi Aplicación Web, pero me arroja un error que dice que item no tiene una definición para currency_id no se si sepan a que se refiera o por que me marca eso.

```
// Agrega credenciales
            SDK.AccessToken = "";
            SDK.ClientId = "";
            SDK.ClientSecret = "";

            // Crea un objeto de preferencia
            Preference preference = new Preference();


            preference.Items.Add(
              new Item()
              {
                  Id = "",
                  PictureUrl = "",
                  Title = "Dummy Item",
                  Description = "Multicolor Item",
                  CategoryId = "",
                  currency_id = "",
                  Quantity = 1,
                  UnitPrice = (decimal)75.56
              }
            );
            preference.Save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Por currency se refiere a la moneda, veo que en el item la defines pero la dejas con un string vacio

si analizamos la documentacion

[Mercado Pago - Personalización](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/payments/web-payment-checkout/v1/personalization)

Veras que en los ejemplos del json que arma defines:

```
"currency_id": "ARS",
```

podrias probar definiendo una moneda

Answer (score -1):

Probablemente estés utilizando el tipo de dato Item incorrecto.

`Preference.Items` es de tipo `MercadoPago.DataStructures.Preference.Item`

Asegúrate que el tipo que estás declarando es el mismo que espera `Preference.Items.`

Comment: Comentarios como este no son aptos para el apartado de respuesta, tu respuesta no aporta una solución calara al problema planteado. Te adjunto [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)  para que te informes de la manera adecuada de responder una pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: Acabo de leer toda la seccion que me adjunta y en realidad no encuentro donde está "mi falta". Mi respuesta es la solución al problema (hace 15 minutos estaba trabajando en ello y tuve que solucionar el mismo problema, fue por eso que la puse. La única respuesta que hay a la pregunta (además de la mía) no responde a la pregunta y además no resuelve el problema, aún así es mí respuesta la que se considera inútil. Aclárame esto porfa. Saludos.

Comment: La otra respuesta esta adjuntando un enlace de documentación que justifica su respuesta, da una razón por la que se genera el error que se plantea en la pregunta, cito: *no se si sepan a que se refiera o por que me marca eso.*, No entiendo por que estás catalogando la otra respuesta como "no aporta una solución", si de una explicación de por que se genera el error y una solución justificada con documentación oficial. Además el OP no ha aceptado ninguna respuesta, es muy pronto para catalogar una respuesta como "inútil".